# pysparksql extract value from a json field in a nested expression

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, relational-database

I have some data that looks like:

```
{ "col1": "val1",
  "col2": "val2",
  "col3": "{ \"a\": \"A\", \"b\": \"B\", .... }"
 }
```

with schema:

```
root:
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
```

based on a certain condition I need to select the value in col3.b

So I have pyspark sql code as follows:

```
spark.sql(''' 
select 
col1, 
col2, 
case when col1 like .... then "yo" 
when col1 like .... then json_tuple(col3,'b') else null end as col_3_val 
from data ''').show()
```

This gives me the error

```
spark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Generators are not supported when it's nested in expressions
```

However when I run

```
spark.sql(''' select json_tuple(col3,'b') as col_3_val from data ''').show()
```

I get the output as expected:

```
col_3_val
B
```

Am I missing something or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using json_tuple. Extract the Json value from the column using REGEXP_EXTRACT(col2, my_regex )